# Angular spectrum method using python

Tags: python, math, fft, physics, numerical-methods

I am trying to numerically propagate a given (electric) field using the angular spectrum method. For this I am following "Principles and Applications of Fourier Optics" (Robert K. Tyson) Chapter 3, Page 2

[image]

I tried to recreate the maths using the following code

```py
import numpy as np
import imageio

U = imageio.imread("ap.png")[:,:, 0] # load circular aperture
_lambda = 800e-9

def propagate2(self,z):
    A = np.fft.fft2(U, norm="ortho") # 2D FFT 
    alpha = np.fft.fftfreq(U.shape[0])*_lambda # direction cosine in x direction
    beta = np.fft.fftfreq(U.shape[1])*_lambda # direction cosine in x direction
    gamma = np.zeros([alpha.shape[0], beta.shape[0]])
    k = 2*np.pi/_lambda # wavevector

    for i,j in itertools.product(range(alpha.shape[0]), range(beta.shape[0])): # determine phase value for each (i,j)
        if alpha[i]**2+beta[j]**2 < 1:
            gamma[i,j] = np.sqrt(1-alpha[i]**2-beta[j]**2)
        else:
            gamma[i,j] = 1j*np.sqrt(np.abs(1-alpha[i]**2-beta[j]**2))
    phi = np.exp(1j*k*z*gamma)
    field = np.fft.ifft2(A*phi, norm="ortho") # 2D IFFT
    return field
```

This code should produce the usual double slit diffraction pattern, however (as to be seen below) won't produce and diffraction at all.

[image: Code output]

I am fairly certain that there is some problem with my alpha and beta values, however I can't seem to find it.
Any help is highly appreciated.

ap.png:

[image: ap.png]

Answer (score 4):

I made a complete implementation of the Angular Spectrum Method using Python:
https://github.com/rafael-fuente/Diffraction-Simulations--Angular-Spectrum-Method

To use it for your example, you need to clone the repository and put your double slit image in the path `./apertures/double_slit.png`

Then, from the repository folder run the following script:

```
from diffractsim import MonochromaticField, mm, nm, cm, ApertureFromImage


F = MonochromaticField(
    wavelength=632.8 * nm, extent_x=5.6 * mm, extent_y=5.6 * mm, Nx=1024, Ny=1024
)

F.add(ApertureFromImage(
   "./apertures/double_slit.jpg", image_size=(4.0* mm, 4.0 * mm), simulation = F))
rgb = F.compute_colors_at(20*cm)
F.plot_colors(rgb, xlim=[-4.5, 4.5], ylim=[-4.5, 4.5])
```

This is the result of the script of the near field (20 cm) for different wavelengths:
[image: Diffraction of a double-slit for different wavelengths]

As we can see in the plots, the higher the light's wavelength, the wider the length of the interference fringes.

You can also compute the diffraction pattern with a broad spectrum, like white light, with the `PolychromaticField class`:

```
from diffractsim import PolychromaticField, cf, mm, cm, ApertureFromImage


F = PolychromaticField(
    spectrum=2 * cf.illuminant_d65, extent_x=5.6 * mm, extent_y=5.6 * mm, Nx=1024, Ny=1024
)

F.add(ApertureFromImage(
    "./apertures/double_slit.png", image_size=(4.0* mm, 4.0 * mm), simulation = F))

rgb = F.compute_colors_at(20*cm)
F.plot_colors(rgb, xlim=[-4.5, 4.5], ylim=[-4.5, 4.5])
```

which results in:

[image: white light double slit angular spectrum method]

The problem with your code is that you are not using the Fast Fourier Transform correctly.

The core of my implementation (propagation of the Angular Spectrum) is in the `MonochromaticField` `propagate` method, in [monochromatic_simulator.py](https://github.com/rafael-fuente/Diffraction-Simulations--Angular-Spectrum-Method/blob/main/diffractsim/monochromatic_simulator.py):

```
def propagate(self, z):
    self.z += z

    # compute angular spectrum
    fft_c = fft2(self.E)
    c = fftshift(fft_c)

    kx = 2*bd.pi*bd.fft.fftshift(bd.fft.fftfreq(simulation.Nx, d = simulation.dx))
    ky = 2*bd.pi*bd.fft.fftshift(bd.fft.fftfreq(simulation.Ny, d = simulation.dy))
    kx, ky = np.meshgrid(kx, ky)
    kz = np.sqrt((2 * np.pi / self.λ) ** 2 - kx ** 2 - ky ** 2)

    # propagate the angular spectrum a distance z
    E = ifft2(ifftshift(c * np.exp(1j * kz * z)))

    # compute Field Intensity
    self.I = np.real(E * np.conjugate(E))
```

You can see that I used the method `fftshift` after performing the FFT to match the definition of the Fourier Transform.

Also, if you want to discard the evanescent fields as you seem you want to do, it's a much better approach to use `numpy.where` instead of looping every pixel, since Python loops are much slower:

```
    # propagate the angular spectrum a distance z
    mask = (2*np.pi/self.λ)**2 - kx**2 - ky**2 > 0
    A = np.where(mask, c*np.exp(1j*kz * z),  0)
    E = ifft2(ifftshift(A))
```

This code should replace the last lines in the `compute_colors_at` method.
Hope that this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It can be tricky to get this right. Here it is:

```
u = ... # this is your 2D complex field that you wish to propagate
z = ... # this is the distance by which you wish to propagate

dx, dy = 1, 1 # or whatever

wavelen = 1 # or whatever
wavenum = 2 * np.pi / wavelen
wavenum_sq = wavenum * wavenum

kx = np.fft.fftfreq(u.shape[0], dx / (2 * np.pi))
ky = np.fft.fftfreq(u.shape[1], dy / (2 * np.pi))

# this is just for broadcasting, the "indexing" argument prevents NumPy
# from doing a transpose (default meshgrid behaviour)
kx, ky = np.meshgrid(kx, ky, indexing = 'ij', sparse = True)

kz_sq = kx * kx + ky * ky

# we zero out anything for which this is not true, see many textbooks on
# optics for an explanation
mask = wavenum * wavenum > kz_sq

g = np.zeros((len(kx), len(ky)), dtype = np.complex_)
g[mask] = np.exp(1j * np.sqrt(wavenum_sq - kz_sq[mask]) * z)

res = np.fft.ifft2(g * np.fft.fft2(u)) # this is the result
```

You probably want to pad u to prevent wrap around. In that case, simply compute g with the shape doubled then slice the result.

Comment: Your code contains the variable `wavenum_sq` which it does not define and will not run.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but `wavenum_sq` is just `wavenum * wavenum`. Added this anyways.